# Add column with join in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, is there a way of adding a column to a DataFrame by means of a join, but in a way that guarantees that the left hand side remains completely unchanged?

This is what I have looked at so far:

leftOuterJoin... but that risks duplicating rows, so one would have to be super-careful to make sure that there are no duplicate keys on the right.  Not exactly robust or performant, if the only way to guarantee safety is to dedupe before the join.

There is a data structure that seems to guarantee no duplicate keys:  PairRDD.  That has a nice method of looking up a key in the key-value table: `YYY.lookup("key")` . Thus one might expect to be able to do `.withColumn("newcolumn", udf((key:String) => YYY.lookup(key)).apply(keyColumn))` but it seems that udfs cannot do this because they apparently cannot access the sqlContext which is apparently needed for the lookup.  If there were a way of using `withColumn` I would be extremely happy because it has the right semantics.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain more on input and desired output?

Comment: Sure.  As input assume a data frame with 20 columns, including one called `"foo"`, and a million rows.  Also assume that there is a lookup table `lut` implemented as a `PairRDD[(String,Float)]` with 50GB of data.  The desired output is a dataframe just like the original but with an additional column `"bar"` equal to the lookup lut(foo), when foo is in the lookup table, and null otherwise.

Comment: I should perhaps add that the original use case involved a function being applied to foo that needed several lookups and the number varied depending on the data, so it did not work nicely as a join, but that is another question.

Comment: join is the best way if your right dataframe is large and before you join you have to make sure there is only one key for joining. Now if the right dataframe is small enough you can create a hashmap and use withcolumn